# Java Swing Deactivate Win7 Aero Glass ONLY for this Process

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, aero-glass

I have a Java Swing Application and in order to run it properly I need to deactivate the Win 7 Aero Glass. I am forced to use some old `Borland DBSwing libraries`.

I do this by stopping the Win7-Service "uxsms" before starting my .jar file:

```
net stop uxsms
java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -jar myApplication.jar
net start uxsms
```

The problem is that this deactivates the Aero Glass Effects for the Whole Desktop.

My Question is, if there is a way to only **deactivate the Aero Glass effect** **for the one .jar file / this java application**, not the whole Desktop.

For example a flag for the JVM something like `-noEffect` or whatever.

I already use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");` in the java source code but this only effects the **Inner Window** not the outside and for some Message Boxes I need to deactivate Aero Glass in order to work properly

[image]

Comment: Rather than messing around with the OS, I would try to debug why your "Login fehlgeschlagen" is displayed like that. Why don't you show us the code for that?

Comment: Problem is that I am forced to use some old libraries. And they have some GUI elements, and they behave right when my "Login fehlgeschlagen" Box is displayed correctly I only use this as an example. So in short there are GUI Elements in external libraries, and I can not change the source code

Comment: The broken rendering looks more like a buggy graphics driver than a general issue with aero glass.